# $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral with its side lengths $AB = 5, BC = 17, CD = 7, AD = 25,$ and $∠ABC + ∠BCD = 270°.$

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral with its side lengths $AB = 5, BC = 17, CD = 7, AD = 25,$ and $∠ABC + ∠BCD = 270°.$ Find the area of the quadrilateral $ABCD$.

Comment: I tried it with different method like Join AC and using perpendiculars, using law of cosine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally!!

[image]

In $\triangle PAD, \; \angle{P} = 90^{\circ}$. From this I got $$x^2 + y^2 = 17^2 \; \text{and} \; 5x + 7y = 131$$ From these two equations I got $x = 15$ and $y = 8$, only possible solution.
Area of $ABCD = 90 \; \text{units}^2$